# Pentagons with specific angles.

Tags: geometry, number-theory, isometry

I have a series of pentagons (let's call them sepentagons) with the following characteristics:

- At one vertex, the internal angle is 60 degrees
- All other vertexes have an internal angle of 120 degrees
- The length of each side is an integer
- The two sides that meet at 60 degrees are the same length

  1. What are all  sepentagons that the longest edge is 5 cm?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Here they are]

Worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: So only four sepentagons?

Comment: So it turns out.